# What are WordPress admin supported browsers?

Tags: admin, browser-compatibility

I am developing a plugin which exposes custom client components, html/css in the admin area. I want to test the cross-browsing compatibility of these components sticking to the actual browsers supported by WordPress.

Is there an official list of browsers supported by WordPress and by which versions?

Answer (score 1):

The "Official" supported browsers list is currently here:

- https://make.wordpress.org/design/handbook/design-guide/browser-support/

You can also use https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserslist-config-wordpress if you use PostCSS, Autoprefixer, stylelint etc

Answer (score 0):

Supported browsers will change with the each [release](https://wordpress.org/news/category/releases/) and [theme](https://github.com/WordPress/twentyseventeen) you have installed. You might want to check the release notes or [issues on trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/tickets/major) to find any incompatibilities.

The best I could find was [Browse Happy](http://browsehappy.com/)
but nothing in the [commits](https://github.com/WordPress/browsehappy/commits/master) narrowed down or showed version support info.

So you might be able to tie latest browser support with how far back you want to [support](http://caniuse.com/) - https://www.impressivewebs.com/release-history-major-browsers/

Based on this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/8865/84219), you might be able to tie this all back to [If your menus or widgets screens broke…](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2011/02/10/if-your-menus-or-widgets-screens-broke/)

> WordPress 3.0.5 was released at the same time as jQuery 1.5. Unfortunately, 1.5 has some backwards incompatible changes that appear to break a number of areas in the admin. The timing is awkward and it looks like it was us. It wasn’t.
>
> There’s nothing we can do about this even for WordPress 3.1, which is freezing at jQuery 1.4.4.
>
> If your theme deregisters jQuery and re-registers jQuery 1.5, then you’ll want to make sure that this change only applies for the frontend, i.e. ! is_admin(). (Or use the wp_enqueue_scripts hook, which only fires for the theme-side.) This might not be obvious — if you’re enqueueing the latest jQuery from, say, Google’s CDN, you’ll be getting 1.5 suddenly, and things will break.
>
> Someone should put together a quick plugin that restores and enforces the bundled jQuery in the admin. I’ll do it later tonight if no one else does.
>
> Reference: [#16508](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16508) and numerous support forum threads.

But 6 months ago, [jQuery.js](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/tree/master/wp-includes/js) was updated to [1.12.4](http://blog.jquery.com/2016/05/20/jquery-1-12-4-and-2-2-4-released/) which shows support for Safari 9 and IE 11 in the [changelog](http://blog.jquery.com/2016/05/20/jquery-1-12-4-and-2-2-4-released/).

Comment: Thanks jgraup, I also saw Browse Happy but found nothing helpful. I am interested in the admin area (not in front-end themes). Maybe we should take a look at WP's own cross-browsing tests.

Comment: I really don't know for sure, but it's going to be tied to the release because that's when the admin section is updated. Maybe JS commits could help as well https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/tree/master/wp-admin/js or browsing with scripts are shipped with WP https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/#core-registered-scripts -- sorry if this isn't helpful.